# Groovy: Preferred Way to Handle Classpath Resource Loading

Tags: groovy, resources, classpath

From my initial research I've found that I can load classpath resources in groovy by the following approaches:

1. this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)
2. ClasspathResourceManager (for which I couldn't find any examples)

So, I wanted to seek opinions on what is the most 'groovy' way of handling classpath resources?

Further more, I have a list of '*.xsd' files under and 'xsd' directory inside my jar. Is there anyway I can do something similar to this, but with classpath resources?

```
List<StreamSource> schemaDefinitions = new File('src/main/resources/xsd')
  .listFiles( { dir, file -> file ==~ /.*\.xsd/ } as FilenameFilter )
  .collect { new StreamSource(it) }

// Looking for something like this:
List<StreamSource> schemaDefinitions = this.getClass().getResource('src/main/resources/xsd')
  .listFiles( { dir, file -> file ==~ /.*\.xsd/ } as FilenameFilter )
  .collect { new StreamSource(it) }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers in turn;

1:

```
String xsd = this.getClass().getResource('/xsd/file.xsd').text
```

And 2:

No. But [there's a library that makes it easy](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

Comment: Thanks Tim for the quick reply! I tried to post the solution I went with here, but I went over the char limit. So, I'm gonna post it as an answer.

Can you please comment on my approach vs. using reflections?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @tim_yates for the quick reply.

Since the library I'm writing is pretty thin, I'm hesitant to introduce a dependency like reflections at the moment, so for now I went with this solution:

```
private List<StreamSource> retrieveSchemaDefinitionsFromClasspath(String classpathXsdDir) {
  ClasspathResourceManager resourceManager = new ClasspathResourceManager()
  List<String> schemaDefinitionFileNames = resourceManager.getReader(classpathXsdDir).text.split()
  schemaDefinitionFileNames.findAll { it ==~ /.*\.xsd$/ }.collect {
    new StreamSource(resourceManager.getReader("$classpathXsdDir/$it"))
  }
}
```

I will take a look at reflections soon and see how I can apply the same. In the meanwhile, could you please comment on my approach vs. using reflections?

Thanks!